# Usage of PostgreSQL JSON columns as a flexible table schema

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm toying with the idea of structuring my PostgreSQL tables in this way:

```
Id: uuid
Structure: JSON
Some_FK: uuid
```

In this case the `Structure` column is a JSON document containing fields that would otherwise be additional columns on the table.  At this point I would basically be using the RDBMS to generate and manage IDs and relationships, while getting the schema flexibility of a document-store.  In this usage the documents themselves aren't linked together (which is difficult to manage), the documents are simply an extension of the row, and the rows are linked together.

Has anyone tried this sort of thing before, or am I crazy to attempt to use the feature this way?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for this site (too open to opinion and discussion rather than concrete answers) but my gut reaction is this: it sounds like you'd basically end up reimplementing a document store like MongoDB, but which happens to use Postgres as the low-level implementation. That might be an interesting project, but I'm not sure what the advantages would be over an existing technology like MongoDB.

Comment: I have set up a similar system at work, minus the UUIDs. It is currently in Postgresql 9.2 and I have indexed the JSON keys using PLV8, but I plan to port that over to 9.3 and use the built-in JSON functions instead (built in to Postgresql 9.3 I mean). It works well, though the database in only about 900GB. The production version is expected to be several TB's.

Comment: @IMSoP point taken about the question.  I had the same thought, but figured where else would I be able to get access to so many experts?  Our reasons for not choosing a purely schemaless database like MongoDB is that our data has fairly decent structure, but we like the flexibility the of schemaless storage model.  Basically, as soon as we realized we needed to maintain relationships and query on them, we knew a document store wouldn't be the best fit for us.

Comment: @bma Have you found the flexibility of the schemaless structure to be helpful alongside the relational aspects for maintaining relationships?  Mainly in terms of 1) ease of change and 2) maintainability

Comment: Your statements seem kind of contradictory to me: if your data has a decent structure, why not just design a schema for it? Are you worried about change in the structure over time? Perhaps what you actually need is a middleware or ORM layer that abstracts the queries in a way that makes schema changes easier (which you'll need anyway to handle the JSON data). Or is there some other sense in which you wouldn't "trust" a traditional schema?

Comment: We have a well-structured database, taking advantage of partitions, FTS, HSTORE, INET, etc. The JSON attributes could have been accomplished with a very undesirable EAV model that I would have leg-wrestled to the ground any of our developers who attempted it. In our case, the JSON attribute allows flexibility for events, which currently consists of about a dozen keys. Those keys change slowly over time though, so we chose JSON to allow us to support transitions between version of the data and to avoid repeated application changes. It works well for us.

Comment: I didn't really answer your question. Yes, using JSON has been very useful handling changes in data for complex types. For simple key-value we are using HSTORE. Maintainability has been fine, no issues to speak of. The lookups over the JSON data is sped up because we generally narrow down the searching using PK's or an other indexed field (client id, date, etc). Oh, and the data integrity guarantees of Postgresql are another consideration in favour or continuing to use an RDBMS over a NoSQL solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more I think about it, the less sense this makes to me: you get none of the advantages of a structured database, powerful SQL queries, data integrity constraints, etc; but you have all the cost of the DBMS sitting there basically unused, and have to write all the tools for manipulating the data yourself.

If there were no systems available for schemaless document stores, this might be a way of writing a prototype for one, but there are - why build a MongoDB clone on top of Postgres when you could just use MongoDB? Perhaps as an abstract project, some kind of hybrid might make sense, but I'd have thought beyond prototyping it would make sense to fork Postgres and rip out the SQL rather than having all that complexity lying unused.

On a practical level, I'm not sure how you're intending foreign keys to work; it sounds like columns which happen to be foreign keys would remain as real columns, but any other columns would be mashed into the JSON document. That would mean that to retrieve the data, you'd still need to hand-craft the SQL with JOIN statements, but then have an additional layer as well to manipulate the fields inside the JSON (e.g. to filter by them). Or perhaps you would hard-code the JSON manipulation into functions in the SQL expression, in which case you might as well just have a normal schema.

If your primary concern with a traditional schema is the cost of changing them once running, perhaps you should be more concerned about the middleware or ORM layer which you need to isolate the schema from the rest of your application. If you have a "schemaless" structure, each row can effectively have a different schema (structure inside the JSON blob) so the application will need to cope with all past versions of the structure for an item type. But if you have multiple tables with defined foreign keys, the wrapper will *also* need to isolate changes to those, such as tables being created or new relationships being defined, which is basically what you'd need for a fully Relational schema.

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful with challenging our thinking about this.

Comment: And your response is a good description of when/why to use each type system, so +1'd and Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar dillema as you. I was all in flexible schema hype but finally I am convinced that in too many cases transactions and integrity checking can't be thrown away once application matures.

In my opinion when you need transactions and want to store loose hierarchical data without introducing new tables or separate DBs the hybrid relation+JSON is the way to go. For example in my application I use JSON columns for:

- file metadata records with EXIF or ZIP directory structure dump
- audit trail and version dump of the row (number of operations saved is small)
- user error history related with record
- statistics and precomputed aggregates
- generally any content which is not needed today but it would be hard to get that data in the future, which is something better than unstructured log file.

Sure it could be done in MongoDB or any other "NoSQL" but why? Now I get:

- one place to store data, one protocol, API etc.
- full consistency,
- transactions,
- cascaded deletes without orphaned documents
- ad hoc analytic queries, with PostgreSQL 9.3 you can easily query [with json functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html), example I want *all users from France with >80% pictures made with Pentax camera this year*,
- I am going to deploy [Postgres-XC](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/intro-whatis.html) soon to achieve scalable master-master,
- with [PLV8](http://code.google.com/p/plv8js/) extension I can do anything with my data I [can imagine](http://legitimatesounding.com/blog/building_a_mongodb_clone_in_postgres_part_1.html).

Comment: We ended up going with Postgres for all the reasons you stated above.  If we need to do JSON stuff in the future we can, but we don't go completely without any referential protections.  We also use Redis for storing certain transitory data that only needs to be loosely tied to entities in our database.

Comment: I agree with this answer. After trying to use mongo for a while, we realized that it was impossible to not have the relational goodness of postgres. We do utilize JSON columns in several places, which would be god awful to do in standard tables because of the complexity of the underlying JSON structure. As far as I see it, with the mature support of JSON in postgres, there is not much need for mongo. And a mixed architecture of mongo and postgres is also tricky.